# Static methods and Jagged Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, jagged-arrays

I am trying to write a static method that returns an integer, takes a 2-dimensional array of integers as a parameter and return the index of the row in the 2-d array (jagged arrays) that has the largest sum of all its elements. Something went wrong along the line and im still trying to figure out. Help please?
Here is the code:

```
 public static int findMaxRow(int[][] maxRows){
        newI= 0;
        newJ= 0;
        for(int i=0; i< maxRows.length; i++) {
            newI += i;
            for(int j=0; j< maxRows.length; j++) {
                newJ += j;
           ``  if( newI > newJ){
               return newI;
             else {
             }
           }
         }
     }
```

Comment: You have two " ` " before your `if` statement, and your missing a closing bracket " } " before your `else` statement. Also, in your code, `newI` will never be greater than `newJ`, since `newI` will only add the value of `i` `maxRows.length` times and `newJ` will add the value of `j` `maxRows.length`^2 times.

Answer (score 1):

You never define the type for `newI` or `newJ`, that can be fixed by preceding their declaration with their intended type (i.e `int`). You also have two " ` " before your if statement, and your missing a closing bracket " } " before your else statement. But those are just syntactical errors. Once you fix those errors you're going to notice that your method is not returning the desired results.

Looking at your code, specifically the for loops.

```
for(int i=0; i< maxRows.length; i++) {
    newI += i;
    for(int j=0; j< maxRows.length; j++) {
        newJ += j;
        // other stuff
    }
 }
```

Let's say that `maxRows.length` equals 3. That means the outer loop is going to run from 0 to 2, so `newI` will equal 3. Meanwhile for each iteration the outer loop makes, the inner loop iterates 3 times. So `newJ` will end up equalling 9. Which is not the right way to go about summing the elements of an array. A better way to go about it, is to iterate over the arrays in the outer loop and sum the elements in the inner loop, then make a comparison completing the outer loop. Like so:

```
int largestRow = 0;
int largestSum = 0;
int sum;

// iterate over each array
for(int i=0; i< maxRows.length; i++) {
    sum = 0; // set and reset sum to zero

    // iterate over each element
    for(int j=0; j< maxRows[i].length; j++) {
        sum += maxRows[i][j];
    }

    // if sum is > the previous largest sum then set largest
    // sum to this new sum and record which row
    if(sum > largestSum) {
        largestRow = i;
        largestSum = sum;
    }
}

return largestRow;
```

Here is an example of what you're trying to accomplish.

```
public class RowSums {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] test = { {1, 5, 7, 0, 9} , {2, 4, 5, 6, 7} , {9, 2, 0, 12, 8, 3} };

        System.out.println(printRows(test));
        System.out.println("The row with the largest sum is row "
                           + findMaxRow(test));
    }

    public static int findMaxRow(int[][] maxRows){
        int largestRow = 0;
        int largestSum = 0;
        int sum;

        // iterate over each array
        for(int i=0; i< maxRows.length; i++) {
            sum = 0; // set and reset sum to zero

            // iterate over each element
            for(int j=0; j< maxRows[i].length; j++) {
                sum += maxRows[i][j];
            }

            // if sum is > the previous largest sum then set largest
            // sum to this new sum and record which row
            if(sum > largestSum) {
                largestRow = i;
                largestSum = sum;
            }
        }

        return largestRow;
     }

    public static String printRows(int[][] rows) {
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder("Rows and their sums:\n");
        int sum;

        for(int x = 0; x < rows.length; x++) {
            s.append("Row [" + x + "] = [ ");
            sum = 0;
            for(int y = 0; y < rows[x].length; y++) {
                s.append(rows[x][y] + " ");
                sum += rows[x][y];
            }
            s.append("]\n");
            s.append("Row [" + x + "]'s sum is " + sum + "\n");
        }

        return s.toString();
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Rows and their sums:
Row [0] = [ 1 5 7 0 9 ]
Row [0]'s sum is 22
Row [1] = [ 2 4 5 6 7 ]
Row [1]'s sum is 24
Row [2] = [ 9 2 0 12 8 3 ]
Row [2]'s sum is 34

The row with the largest sum is row 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifying your program, the following example will return the index of the row that has the largest sum of elements in it.

Let us suppose our array to be passed is:

```
int [][] maxRows = {{1,2,3}, {1,2,3,4,5}, {9,9,9,9}, {1,2}};
```

passing this array in the method

```
     public static int findMaxRow(int[][] maxRows){
        int sum = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

       int biggestIndex= 0;
       for(int i = 0; i<maxRows.length; i++){
           int temp = 0;
           for(int ir : maxRows[i]){
            temp+=ir;
           }
          if(temp>sum){
             sum = temp;
             biggestIndex = i;
         }
      }

            return biggestIndex;

     }
```

The above program will return the index of the inner array which has the largest sum of elements, in above case, it will return `2` .